# Why does the CentOS 6.6 events/0 kernel thread get stuck in Uninterruptible sleep (D) state?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos6

I am experiencing a very strange problem affecting one of my HP DL160 servers running CentOS 6.6 Linux.  After about 24 hours past a fresh boot of the OS, all of the ssh connections into it will periodically freeze and stop responding for several minutes, recover and then freeze again.  I have noticed that during the freeze period the [events/0] process will be in the D state (Uninterruptible sleep)

```
macferd:~ jmehring$ ssh -l root hpc-laird.usc.edu 'ps auwx | grep events | grep -v grep'
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        D    Apr28   0:28 [events/0]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr28   0:02 [events/1]
root        37  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr28   0:02 [events/2]
root        38  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr28   0:02 [events/3]
root        39  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr28   0:02 [events/4]
root        40  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr28   0:02 [events/5]
root        41  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr28   0:01 [events/6]
root        42  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Apr28   0:02 [events/7]
```

Strangely, I am able to create new ssh connections into the machine and if I run a command as part of the ssh connection it will complete and return the result. I did an strace on one of the previously connected sshd processes and see the following.

```
read(9, "\n\33(B\33[m\33[39;49m\33[31m   48 root  "..., 16384) = 220
write(3, "\223d\205g<\265ypY\3513/\16Ee\275#\1RT\301\205\371\35\227\20l\332w\275\335\377"..., 4144) = 4144
select(10, [3 5 9], [3], NULL, NULL)    = 1 (out [3])
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
write(3, "CD\346\371H\326\4[\360l\212`Q'\371V\\/g\311<\276\230<\f\276\262\314\3509\353\273"..., 256) = 256
select(10, [3 5 9], [], NULL, NULL

<< FREEZE HAPPENS HERE AND THEN CONTINUES >>

)     = 2 (in [3 9])
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
read(9, "\33[H\33(B\33[mtop - 16:05:33 up 1 day"..., 16384) = 4095
```

Doing an lsof on the process reveals that 10 is the /dev/ptmx file descriptor.

```
sshd    21168 root    0u   CHR                1,3      0t0    4165 /dev/null
sshd    21168 root    1u   CHR                1,3      0t0    4165 /dev/null
sshd    21168 root    2u   CHR                1,3      0t0    4165 /dev/null    sshd    21168 root    3r  IPv4             103101      0t0     TCP XXXX:ssh->XXXX:38579 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    21168 root    4w  unix 0xffff880871ae4f00      0t0  103150 socket
sshd    21168 root    5u  FIFO                0,8      0t0  103153 pipe
sshd    21168 root    6w  FIFO                0,8      0t0  103153 pipe
sshd    21168 root    7u   CHR                5,2      0t0    5863 /dev/ptmx
sshd    21168 root    9u   CHR                5,2      0t0    5863 /dev/ptmx
sshd    21168 root   10u   CHR                5,2      0t0    5863 /dev/ptmx
```

A reboot clears up this condition but it starts happening again roughly 24 hours later.

I am suspecting a hardware issue but there is no log or dmesg output that indicates what could be happening.  I have 3 other DL160 machines running this same install of CentOS 6.6 without any problems.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can figure out what is causing the events/0 thread to block?

Comment: `ssh` uses `/dev/ptmx` file (details in [man ptmx](http://linux.die.net/man/4/ptmx)). `select()` syscall waits for this file. Seems like this `select()` syscall is executing in `[events/0]` process (square brackets mean that this process is kernel thread, `/0` means that this process is running on first CPU).

Comment: Looks like this is the same issue described here. http://serverfault.com/questions/648174/ssh-terminal-hangs-tty-ldisc-hangup

Comment: There is a new RHEL kernel available with the fix. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1179703

Comment: So, seems like you solved your problem :)